# Shared library not seeing resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two wpf solutions that use the same class library (one I have written). The library references sytles (as static resources) that are in a resource dictionary of the main project. In one of those solutions, the library finds these static resources in the resource dictionary but in the other project the static resources are not resolved. In both cases the Resource dictionary is declared in the App.Xaml of the main application as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StoryMakerStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\GlassButton.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Slider.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Where StoryMakerStyle.xaml is the name of the resource dictionary in one app. It is called FlashcardsStyle.xaml in the other. The other 2 ResourceDictionary references are the same in both solutions.

Any suggestions as to why references to the resource dictionary are resolved in one solution but not the other?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is a solution of 2 project. You need to specify which project when referencing the ResourceDictionaries like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/ProjectNamespace;Resources/GlassButton.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="/ProjectNamespace;Resources\Slider.xaml" />
```

Comment: I should clarify my question: I should have said I have two wpf solutions, not projects. In one of those solutions, the library finds these static resources in the resource dictionary. The 2 ResourceDictionary references are the same in both solutions. Any suggestions as to why references to the resource dictionary are resolved in one solution but not the other? Thanks

Comment: @user3226682 If you're trying to reference between two completely different non-built solutions what you can do is use StreamReader and XamlReader to load the external .xaml file dynamically. Another solution is build a library separate that contains the needed XAML and reference it that way.

Comment: I really don't recommend referencing between two separate solutions. If there's only a single project in each and they are related to each other I'd combine them into a single project. If that isn't true then I'd personally either copy the files to each solution or work on it in a separate text editor and have both solutions just load the XAML externally.

Comment: Creating just one solution (and setting the project I wanted to work on as the startup project) seems to have fixed this. Thanks for the comments. I should clarify I just added the project for the second solution as another project in the first solution. Making only one project would not have worked for me.